# calcular quantas horas entre data da abertura do chamado e data atual em pl/sql

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

preciso fazer uma consulta que traga os chamados que estão fora do SLA de 48 hrs calculando as datas e horas da abertura do chamado e data atual, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Discordo , é uma questão pertinente.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, você pode usar DATEDIFF (https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/column_conversion_functions011.htm#GWURF780).

Também pode usar as abordagens sugeridas neste post do SoEN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql .

Depois que encontrar a diferença entre as datas basta restringir aquelas cujo valor seja maior que 48 horas, no seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Subtrair duas datas em Oracle resulta na diferença em dias (ou fração) , para saber em horas , multiplique por 24.

Algo como.

```
Select ...
From tabela
Where ...
And (datachamado - sysdate) * 24 >= 48
...
```